# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp

I am getting this error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'` when i run the project using gulp. 
[image]

The package.json dependencies are :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Node js version is `v7.2.0` and npm version is `3.10.9`

Comment: is there a reason you're running super old versions of everything? try upgrading to later versions, it might be these versions are incompatible. and did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes its very old project. i have to just update 3-4 things in the project. i don't have that much bandwidth to upgrade in new version because in node 12.x + all the syntax are changed. yes i have run npm install and react package is available in the node_modules

Comment: if you have any other solution to fix this issue please tell me

Comment: can you share the line it's breaking on? did you do `import react` instead of `import React` it should be `React` not `react`

Comment: `var React = require('react');` it's breaking on this line

Comment: have you tried `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm install` again?

Comment: yes, i have tried `rm -rf node_modules` and also i have tried to delete `package-lock.json` and `npm install` but no luck

Comment: what file is this in? `var React = require('react'); `?

Comment: Its a ES5 syntax of importing the package

Comment: yeh I know but I'm saying what file is it

Comment: this is in `app.js` which is entrypoint file

Comment: its fixed, actually the problem is in `sanitize-html`. i have changed the version from `^1.12.0` to `1.12.0`. Thank you so much for your time @RedBaron

Comment: no worries, glad you solved it :)